# How to declare a complexType has only one child element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

When using XML Schema to declare that a `complexType` has just one child element, all the below three approaches achieve the goal:

```
<xs:complexType> <xs:sequence> <xs:element ref="somevalue"/> </xs:sequence> </xs:comlexType>
<xs:complexType> <xs:choice>   <xs:element ref="somevalue"/> </xs:choice>   </xs:comlexType>
<xs:complexType> <xs:all>      <xs:element ref="somevalue"/> </xs:all>      </xs:comlexType>
```

Apparently, the `sequence`, `choice` and `all` are not necessary to for a single element, because they should by used to indicate the order of multiple elements. **Is there a more concise way to declare a `complexType` that has only one child element?** (I.e. one that eliminates the use of `sequence`, `all` or `choice`, somehow.)

Comment: [Early working drafts of the schema spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xmlschema-1-20000407/#declare-type) assumed an implicit `sequence` if you nested `element` declarations directly inside a `complexType`, but this was removed before the spec reached its final form in favour of always requiring an explicit `sequence`, `choice` or `all`.

Comment: OKay,I will pick the sequence :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just eliminating `xs:sequence`, `xs:choice`, or `xs:all`, is not an option:

```
  <xs:complexType name="cType">
    <xs:element name="e"/> 
  </xs:complexType>
```

is not valid.

See [XML Representation of Complex Type Definitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-type) where `complexType`'s content model is defined as follows:

> (annotation?, (simpleContent | complexContent | ((group | all
>   | choice | sequence)?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*,
>   anyAttribute?))))

There is no provision for `element` being a direct child of `complexType`.

Comment: Your explanation and URL make everything clear, thank you! so it looks like XML Schema does not provide a compact way to declare single element complexType, where I must always put a single element into all | choice | sequence | group.

Comment: You can for all | choice | sequence | group add the restriction maxOccurs = "1", which will at least limit the amount of occurances to only one:

Comment: @DEX: `maxOccurs` already defaults to `1`. Besides, OP's question is about omitting `xs:sequence`, `xs:choice`, or `xs:all` altogether for the simple case where only single child element is allowed.  (Answer as stated: Not permitted.)